# How to move menus in the footer to the right?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue trying to move menus to the right hand side of the page. I tried using a float:right but it changes the order of the menus and I have been trying to add a flex end but doesn't seem to work, not sure if I'm calling on the wrong element.

If you view the screenshot below, I want the 4 footer menus (account, shop, about and barista coffee) to be moved to the right of this footer. The column that has the logo, social icons and address should remain where it is. How do I move it?

Screenshot:

[image]

HTML (I commented where the four menus are - see shift to right comment):

```css
footer [id*=nav_menu] {
  width: auto;
  float: right; /*this moves it to the right but changes the order and messes up with the pay icons underneath*/
}

aside#text-4 .textwidget,
footer [class*=menu] ul,
footer [id*=nav_menu] .widget_title {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer_wrap widget_area scheme_original">

  <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
    <aside id="text-4" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_text">
      <div class="textwidget">
        <div class="logofooteri"><img src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/123d.png"></div>
        <div class="socialfooter" style="display: inline-block;">
          <p>
            <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.instagram.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Instagramwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/balancecoffee20" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Facebookwhite.svg" width="29px" height="29px"></a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://twitter.com/BalanceCoffeeUK" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Twitterwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.pinterest.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Pinterestwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-address">Kemp House, 152-160 City Road,<br> London, EC1V 2NX</div>
        <div class="footer-address">info@balancecoffee.co.uk</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Shift to the right -->

    </aside>
    <aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_10 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h5 class="widget_title">ACCOUNT</h5>
      <div class="menu-account-footer-container">
        <ul id="menu-account-footer-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7970"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=285">Sign In</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7971"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=6089">Earn Rewards</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7968"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4561">Manage Subscription</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7969"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1109">FAQs</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7967"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1032">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget_number_11 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h5 class="widget_title">SHOP</h5>
      <div class="menu-shop-footer-container">
        <ul id="menu-shop-footer-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-7995"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?cat=69">Coffee</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7978"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=subscription-coffee">Subscription Coffee</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7980"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=coffee-equipment">Coffee Equipment</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7989"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4757">Sage Coffee Machines</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7979"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=oat-milk-coffee-bundles">Oat Milk</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7985"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=coffee-gifts">Coffee Gifts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <aside id="nav_menu-8" class="widget_number_12 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h5 class="widget_title">ABOUT</h5>
      <div class="menu-about-footer-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-about-footer-menu-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8015"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1012">Our Story</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8038"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1054">Sustainability</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8041"><a href="/">Press</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8042"><a href="/">Become an Affiliate</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8043"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=2410">Become a Stocklist</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <aside id="nav_menu-9" class="widget_number_13 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h5 class="widget_title">BARISTA SCHOOL</h5>
      <div class="menu-barista-school-footer-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-barista-school-footer-menu-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8035"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3249">Coffee Blog</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8032"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4757">Sage Coffee Machines</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8031"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3238">Coffee Videos</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8033"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3241">Coffee Recipes</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8034"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3252">Tips &amp; Hacks</a></li>


      </div>
      <!-- /.columns_wrap -->

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I'll suggest you to read how [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) works,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with `display: flex` and `justify-content: flex-end` for the `.footer_wrap_inner`:

```css
.footer_wrap_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

To get the first `aside` with the id `text-4` to the left you could simply use `margin-rigth: auto`:

```css
aside#text-4 {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

**Working example:** (*with some additional css for better visability*)

By the way the `p` tags in the `.socialfooter` prevent the icons from being displayed inline like in your screenshot - so i removed them. I also changed the headings from `h5` to `h3` to have the look from the screenshot.

```css
* {
  color: white;
}

.footer_wrap_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #000;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logofooteri img {
  width: 180px;
}

footer [id*=nav_menu] {
  width: auto;
}

aside#text-4 .textwidget>div {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

aside#text-4 {
  margin-right: auto;
}

aside#text-4 .textwidget,
footer [class*=menu] ul,
footer [id*=nav_menu] .widget_title,
.socialfooter {
  text-align: left;
}

aside#text-4 a {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer_wrap widget_area scheme_original">

  <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
    <aside id="text-4" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_text">
      <div class="textwidget">
        <div class="logofooteri">
          <img src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/123d.png">
        </div>
        <div class="socialfooter">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">
            <img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Instagramwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px">
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/balancecoffee20" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">
            <img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Facebookwhite.svg" width="29px" height="29px">
          </a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/BalanceCoffeeUK" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">
            <img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Twitterwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px">
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">
            <img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Pinterestwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-address">Kemp House, 152-160 City Road,<br> London, EC1V 2NX</div>
        <div class="footer-address">info@balancecoffee.co.uk</div>
      </div>
    </aside>

      <!--***** Shift to the right **********-->
      
    <aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_10 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h3 class="widget_title">ACCOUNT</h5>
      <div class="menu-account-footer-container">
        <ul id="menu-account-footer-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7970">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=285">Sign In</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7971">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=6089">Earn Rewards</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7968">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4561">Manage Subscription</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7969">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1109">FAQs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7967">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1032">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    
    <aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget_number_11 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h3 class="widget_title">SHOP</h5>
      <div class="menu-shop-footer-container">
        <ul id="menu-shop-footer-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-7995">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?cat=69">Coffee</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7978">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=subscription-coffee">Subscription Coffee</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7980">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=coffee-equipment">Coffee Equipment</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7989">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4757">Sage Coffee Machines</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7979">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=oat-milk-coffee-bundles">Oat Milk</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7985">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=coffee-gifts">Coffee Gifts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    
    <aside id="nav_menu-8" class="widget_number_12 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h3 class="widget_title">ABOUT</h5>
      <div class="menu-about-footer-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-about-footer-menu-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8015">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1012">Our Story</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8038">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1054">Sustainability</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8041">
            <a href="/">Press</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8042">
            <a href="/">Become an Affiliate</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8043">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=2410">Become a Stocklist</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    
    <aside id="nav_menu-9" class="widget_number_13 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h3 class="widget_title">BARISTA SCHOOL</h5>
      <div class="menu-barista-school-footer-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-barista-school-footer-menu-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8035">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3249">Coffee Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8032">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4757">Sage Coffee Machines</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8031">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3238">Coffee Videos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8033">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3241">Coffee Recipes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8034">
            <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3252">Tips &amp; Hacks</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.columns_wrap -->
    </aside>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/59kor2Ls/

Your HTML is invalid for starters, but this fiddle is literally all you need to start that sort of layout.

```css
.footer_wrap_inner {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer_wrap widget_area scheme_original">
  <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
    <aside id="text-4" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_text">
      <div class="textwidget">
        <div class="logofooteri"><img src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/123d.png"></div>
        <div class="socialfooter" style="display: inline-block;">
          <p>
            <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.instagram.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Instagramwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/balancecoffee20" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Facebookwhite.svg" width="29px" height="29px"></a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://twitter.com/BalanceCoffeeUK" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Twitterwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <a style="margin-right: 12px;" href="https://www.pinterest.com/balancecoffee" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img loading="lazy" src="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Pinterestwhite.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></a>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-address">Kemp House, 152-160 City Road,<br> London, EC1V 2NX
        </div>
        <div class="footer-address">info@balancecoffee.co.uk</div>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_10 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h5 class="widget_title">ACCOUNT</h5>
      <div class="menu-account-footer-container">
        <ul id="menu-account-footer-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7970"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=285">Sign In</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7971"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=6089">Earn Rewards</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7968"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4561">Manage Subscription</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7969"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1109">FAQs</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7967"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1032">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget_number_11 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h5 class="widget_title">SHOP</h5>
      <div class="menu-shop-footer-container">
        <ul id="menu-shop-footer-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-7995"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?cat=69">Coffee</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7978"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=subscription-coffee">Subscription Coffee</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7980"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=coffee-equipment">Coffee Equipment</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7989"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4757">Sage Coffee Machines</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7979"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=oat-milk-coffee-bundles">Oat Milk</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-7985"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?product_cat=coffee-gifts">Coffee Gifts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <aside id="nav_menu-8" class="widget_number_12 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
      <h5 class="widget_title">ABOUT</h5>
      <div class="menu-about-footer-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-about-footer-menu-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8015"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1012">Our Story</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8038"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1054">Sustainability</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8041"><a href="/">Press</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8042"><a href="/">Become an Affiliate</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8043"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=2410">Become a Stocklist</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <aside id="nav_menu-9" class="widget_number_13 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">

      <h5 class="widget_title">BARISTA SCHOOL</h5>
      <div class="menu-barista-school-footer-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-barista-school-footer-menu-1" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8035"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3249">Coffee Blog</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8032"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4757">Sage Coffee Machines</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8031"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3238">Coffee Videos</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8033"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3241">Coffee Recipes</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8034"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=3252">Tips &amp; Hacks</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </aside>
    <!-- /.columns_wrap -->
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad html, I tried to reduce the code in the question and must have made a mistake during the edit

Answer (score -1):

Here is a clean code without the unnecessary code. The idea is arranging items in containers using flexbox.

- We have footer which is a container with two containers inside it. The containers inside have space between them i.e. `justify-content: space-between;`.
- The second child container has four more containers inside it.

Code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sanamumtaz/pen/zYwZowL)